# Spring boot gradle + lombok - Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath has been deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Whwn I create new `gradle Spring boot application` on https://start.spring.io/

I have `gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip` in wrapper properies.

1) Why is this version of the gradle used by default? already exists version **5.0**

2) If I add lombok dependency to project and try compile I get this:

> Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath has been
>   deprecated. Gradle 5.0 will ignore annotation processors on the
>   compile classpath. The following annotation processors were detected
>   on the compile classpath:
>   'org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor'
>   and 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' and
>   'lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor' and
>   'lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$ClaimingProcessor'.  Please
>   add them to the annotation processor path instead. If you did not
>   intend to use annotation processors, you can use the '-proc:none'
>   compiler argument to ignore them.

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer regarding question 1.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 2): it seems you are adding `lombok` dependency in a wrong (deprecated) configuration ( `compile`, maybe?): you should use dedicated `annotationProcessor` configuration for  this kind of dependency:

```
dependencies {        

    /* -------------- Lombok -----------------------------------------------------*/
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

}
```

For question 1) : Gradle release 5.0 is quite recent, the Spring Initializer has not yet been updated to use this version by default, I guess.

*EDIT* : see open PR related to the use of Gradle 5 : https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/741

*EDIT 2*  now (04/04/2019) Spring Initializr generates Gradle projects using Gradle version 5.2.1 .